# Exibir PDF com callback do AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, pdf, jasper

Tenho uma função que me retorna um documento em PDF gerado pelo Jasper no backend:

```
RestSrv.find(url, function (data) {
    $scope.report = data;
});
```

..

```
{{report}}
```

Joguei o retorno no scopo e tentei exibir ele, porem ele não exibiu o PDF na nova pagina WEB, exibiu os caracteres especiais do documento, resumindo, não sei uma forma de exibir o documento PDF para o usuário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui exibir o relatório usando editando aquele trecho para:

```
    $http.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
        .success(function (data) {
            var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            window.open(fileURL);
        });
```

dessa forma o meu retorno em PDF é exibido de forma legível.